# Singular complex and homotopy coherent nerve as simplicial sets

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, simplicial-categories

Let $X$ be a CW complex.

Is the simplicial set $\ \mathrm{Sing}\ X$ isomorphic to the homotopy coherent nerve of some Kan enriched category?

Is this true for $X$ = the real line?

Comment: It might be annoying to actually prove that the answer is no, but the point is that $Sing(X)$ typically has no strictly associative composition of paths, whereas the homotopy-coherent nerve of a simplicial category does - the tools we have to prove that a structure doesn't exist are mostly homotopy-theoretic, and here is there is no homotopy-theoretic obstruction to such a thing. But the answer should be "no" in general

Comment: Why exactly is an isomorphism (as opposed to a simplicial homotopy equivalence) desirable here?